# C++ vectors, const char *, variables scope and lifetime

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, vector

This piece of code is supposed to parse requests, extracts the URI path, then extract each individual header and its value then pass all those extracted variables into `std::vector <const char*> cva` which will be ultimately passed to `std::vector<std::vector<const char*>> nv  (config.nv.push_back(std::move(cva));)`

**I have few problems here:**

- It seems that the parsing is happening correctly but the way I am storing/passing the content of extracted variable is not working properly either due to a misunderstanding of how variables are stored/retrieved and their scope in C++ (most likely since I barely started learning C++) or some bigger issue that I am not aware of.
- I have inserted some `print` statements which show that my parsing has been done correctly.
- However the `for` loops (at the end) have different output then expected.

## i

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>  
#include <string> 

namespace {
std::vector<std::string> explode(const std::string& str, const char& ch) {
std::string next;
std::vector<std::string> result;

// For each character in the string
for (std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++) {
    // If we've hit the terminal character
    if (*it == ch) {
        // If we have some characters accumulated
        if (!next.empty()) {
            // Add them to the result vector
            result.push_back(next);
            next.clear();
        }
    } else {
        // Accumulate the next character into the sequence
        next += *it;
    }
}
if (!next.empty())
     result.push_back(next);
return result;
}
}

int main() {
// this is an example of how my reqlines looks like
   std::vector<std::string> reqlines;
   reqlines.push_back("https://endpoint/test1");
   reqlines.push_back("https://endpoint/test2\theader1:1234\tcookie:abcd");
   reqlines.push_back("https://endpoint/test3\theader1:5678");
   reqlines.push_back("https://endpoint/test4");
   reqlines.push_back("https://endpoint/test5");

   std::vector<std::string> paths;
   std::vector<std::string> extraheaders;
   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > tokenized;
   int count = 0;   // keeps track of each request number so I can access its corresponding extra headers from extraheaders vector
   bool cond = true;

   if (cond){
    // creating which will be used to store my requests paths as well as extra headers
    // This has to be a const char * vector since it will be used by an external library which requires such type
    std::vector<const char *> cva;

    for (auto &req : reqlines){
            unsigned int pos = req.find_first_of("\t", 0);
            if (pos == -1){
                    paths.push_back(req);
                    extraheaders.push_back(" ");
            } else {
                    paths.push_back(req.substr(0, pos));
                    extraheaders.push_back(req.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos));
            }
    }

    for (auto &path : paths){
            cva.push_back(":path");
            cva.push_back(path.c_str()); // adding the URI path into cva variable  

            // explode function which returns a std::vector<std::string> when passing an std::string to it
            tokenized.push_back(explode(extraheaders[count], '\t'));  // extracting the vector<std::string> of all extra headers

    //      if (tokenized[count][0].compare(" ") == 0){
    //              printf("   %d   element is empty is skipped  \n");
    //      }else { 

            for (auto &tok : tokenized[count]){   // looping through extra headers of request number "count", parsing header name/value and adding it to cva
                printf(" %d   tok  %s\n", __LINE__, tok.c_str());
                printf(" %d   tok address    %d\n", __LINE__, &tok);
                unsigned int pos = tok.find_first_of(":", 0);
                if (pos == -1 )
                    printf("  %d  there are no headers \n", __LINE__);
                else {
                    printf("header name:   %s\n", (tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str());
                    printf("header value:   %s\n", (tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str());
                    cva.push_back((tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str());
                    cva.push_back((tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str());
                }
            }
            cva.push_back(":version");  // adding version header
            cva.push_back("HTTP/1.1");  // adding version header number
            cva.push_back(nullptr);  // adding nullptr (which is how nv is expecting cva to be terminated)
            count++;

            // passing the cva content to nv 
            //config.nv.push_back(std::move(cva));
    }

    // Below are the printing statement to check the values of the different variables I created and populated 
    // above, my problem is that the population process puts some values into my variables however printing
    // the content of the those variables shows different values from what I am expecting

            std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Printing cva" << std::endl;
            for (auto &elem : cva){
                    if (elem == nullptr)
                            std::cout << static_cast<void*>(nullptr) << std::endl;
                    else
                            std::cout << &elem << "   " <<elem << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Printing paths" << std::endl;
            for (auto &path : paths){
                    std::cout << &path << "    " << path << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "          " << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Printing headers" << std::endl;
            for (auto &hed : extraheaders) {
                    std::cout << &hed << "    "<<hed << std::endl;
            }
    }
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
Printing cva
:path
endpoint:port/test1
:version
HTTP/1.1
0
:path
endpoint:port/test2
:header1
1234
:cookie
abcd
:version
HTTP/1.1
0
:path
endpoint:port/test3
:header1
5678
:version
HTTP/1.1
0
:path
endpoint:port/test4
:version
HTTP/1.1
0
:path
endpoint:port/test5
:version
HTTP/1.1
0
```

The actual output:

```
 Printing cva
   :path
   endpoint:port/test1
   :version
   HTTP/1.1
   0
   :path
   endpoint:port/test2
   header1  // for test2 request, header1 value is 1234
   5678
   header1  // header 1 should not be printed twice
   5678
            // Missing cookie header and value
   :version
   HTTP/1.1
   0
   :path
   endpoint:port/test3
   header1
   5678
   :version
   HTTP/1.1
   0
   :path
   endpoint:port/test4
   :version
   HTTP/1.1
   0
   :path
   endpoint:port/test5
   :version
   HTTP/1.1
   0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                cva.push_back((tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str());
                cva.push_back((tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str());
```

This part is undefined behavior.

`cva` is a vector of `const char *`, native pointers. You are invoking a temporary object's `c_str()`, here. This temporary `std::string` object immediately goes out of scope, and gets destroyed, at the end of the expression, at which point the `const char *` to its internal contents is no longer valid. This pointer, to the internal contents of a destroyed object gets added to the `cva` vector, and later an attempt is made to print it, hence the undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Knowing that the cva vactor of `const char *` is used by another external library and I can't change it. What is the best approach to bypass this undefined behavior. i.e shall I copy the content of  `(tok.substr(0, pos)).c_str()` and `(tok.substr(pos+1, std::string::npos)).c_str()` into other variables and then pass those variables to the `cva.push_back()`. or is there a better, more elegant way to handle this use case?

Comment: Yes, you need to copy the actual string to a separate vector, and **after** all strings are copied, construct a separate vector of `const char *`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Since I am learning C++, is it ok if I post the solution I figured out so I can get some feedback on it and what are the best practices? There are certainly some things that would make the code more elegant and more efficient and I would like to get this kind of feedback from C++ experts!